# DIY Baking Steel?

Tags: baking

I am interested in baking on a baking steel. I was wondering if there is an inexpensive DIY way to make one out of steel plate purchased from a local metal retailer or if it would end up costing the same as purchasing a baking steel as a finished product? I found one DIY page on the web at https://www.kamadoguru.com/topic/39939-diy-baking-steel/
but would want to know that the process yields a food-grade result. Any advice or suggestions that someone might share with me would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Lemme second the need to season the steel like the linked guide says; I made my own and didn't season it properly, and it was rusty by the 2nd use.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Steels are alloys of different compositions of iron carbon and other metals. Not all steels are considered safe for food as some contain metals or additives that could in some circumstances leach into food, so not just any steel will do.

Baking steels are usually made of A36 steel or stainless steel:

- A36 is not stainless, it's commonly used for structural members but is also a popular choice for restaurant griddles. It isn't stainless so it will rust, so you will first have to get the rust off and then oil the steel after every use or season it. It's cheap and has good conductivity
- Stainless steel (316 or 430, not 304 as that tends to pit) is more expensive and doesn't conduct heat as well as A36 steel, but it's a lot less maintenance as you don't have to worry about keeping up the seasoning. You can wash these to clean them

Depending on where you are you can get just about any steel cut and shipped to you at any size and thickness. If you ask the shop may soften the edges for you, which is important for safety, if they don't you can do it yourself with an angle grinder and a metal grinding disc. This sounds scary but it's actually pretty easy, just wear eye protection, gloves and old clothes. Whatever steel you buy will need to be cleaned to get any coatings or industrial by-products off before use.

Comment: An alternative to an amgle grinder would be a hand file. Probably only 30-60 minutes work. It's not that much steal

Comment: @DaPara It's very limiting in size, but you could use a cast iron pan. Flip it if you dont want to deal with the sides.

Comment: I'd just buy a ready-made one @DaPara, there's many options out there and they aren't crazy money.

Comment: Also, depending on your access to metal wholesalers or not, you might find that you're not saving much money compared with a commercial one.  The original is $90, knock-offs are around $50, and a steel plate that size set me back around $24 at a scrapyard, plus half a day with a angle grinder.  If I decide I want one again, I'm getting a commercial one.

Comment: How are you finding the experience of your DIY one @FuzzyChef?

Comment: I bought a pizza oven and left it to rust.  So ... I wasn't impressed.

Answer (score 1):

My son works in a welding shop.  He cut me a piece of A36 12x18 and 1/4 inch thick.  Cost me $24 and some change.  I made pizza on it today.  It was AMAZING!!  I am a believer.

Answer (score 1):

I went to my local machine shop and purchased a 14" x 16" 1/4" steel.  He rounded the corners for me and softened the edges.  When I got home I put it in a tub with 1 gallon of vinegar and 1 gallon of water.  soaked it for 2 days.  took it out and sprayed it with simple green and then rubbed it with a piece of 00 steel wool.  Took my angle grinder with a 120 grit flap sander and smoothed the edges.  That took less than 15 minutes.  It turned out fantastic.  I rubbed crisco on all surfaces and put it in the oven. It is now in the oven at 475° for an hour.  will turn the oven off and let it sit for 2 hours. then repeat two more times.  Sure beats spending $100 on something so simple.  Especially when I have a pizza oven and pizza stones already.